# Options Pattern in ASP.NET Core - how to return sub-options as a JSON string (not strongly typed)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

The following documentation illustrates how to use the Options Pattern in ASP.NET Core to create a strongly-typed options class to access JSON configuration data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options

This C# class

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public string Option1 { get; set; }
    public int Option2 { get; set; }
}
```

represents a portion of this JSON configuration file (the first two root-level properties)

```
{
  "option1": "value1_from_json",
  "option2": -1,
  "subOptions": {
    "subOption1": "subvalue1_from_json",
    "subOption2": 200
  }
}
```

I want to add another C# property named **SubOptions** to the *MyOptions* class that returns the raw data of the *subOptions* JSON sub-section, without creating a strongly-typed class for that sub-section of the JSON configuration file, but I don't know what data type to use (or if it's even possible to do that).

If I use **string**, I get a runtime error when `service.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);` is called, saying *System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.*

If I use **object** or **dynamic**, I get a different runtime error when `service.AddSingleton(cfg => cfg.GetService<IOptions<MyOptions>>().Value);` is called to register an instance of the MyOptions class, saying **System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type'**

If I use **JObject**, I get `{}` back when I access the *SubOptions* property of the MyOptions object that's injected into my API Controller.

I know I can convert the sub-section to a JSON string property by escaping the sub-section data, but I want to avoid treating the sub-section as a string, and instead leave it as raw JSON.

**Is it possible to do what I want to do?  Is there a data type that works with the Options Pattern that will allow me to access the JSON sub-section without having to create a strongly-typed class?**

*For background, I'm trying to create an API Controller method that returns the content of the JSON sub-section to the API client. I want to avoid using a strongly-typed class for the sub-section, so that the JSON configuration file can be edited on the server, adding new properties and values to the sub-section that will be returned to the API client, without having to update the C# code and redeploy the API service. In other words, I want the JSON sub-section to be 'dynamic', and just pull it and send it to the client. *

Comment: If you use Json.net there's an object type called `JObject` that I think you could use.

Comment: Actually @404, there was a typo in my original post. If I use JObject, it doesn't cause a runtime error, but returns nothing (the configuration data isn't reflected in the MyOptions property)

Answer (score 1):

You can sorta do get raw configuration object by forcing your SubOptions property to be of `IConfigurationSection`:

```cs
public class MyOptions
{
    public string Option1 { get; set; }
    public int Option2 { get; set; }
    public IConfigurationSection SubOptions { get; set; } // returns the "raw" section now
    public string SubOptions_take2 { get; set; }
}
```

so you would still bind your strongly typed object in your Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);
    ...
}
```

but this is where luck appears to run out, because even though it is a whole section - as far as options binder is concerned it's all been deserialised and parsed into hierarchy of values already. There appears to be no easy way to reassemble it back into one string. Injecting `IOptionsMonitor` allows you to get the values by opting for `.GetChildren()` but I could not find an obvious way to get the whole hierarchy without writing custom code to just recursively walk it (which I will leave out for you to play with should you feel this is worth the effort):

```cs
public IndexModel(IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> options)
{
    _options = options.CurrentValue;

    var subOptions = _options.SubOptions as ConfigurationSection;
    var children = subOptions.GetChildren(); // you see, the config has already been parsed into this hierarchy of items - it's too late to get the raw string value
    var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(children);
    // will produce something like this JSON:
    //[{"Path":"SubOptions:subOption1","Key":"subOption1","Value":"subvalue1_from_json"},{"Path":"SubOptions:subOption2","Key":"subOption2","Value":"200"}]    
}
```

one way around it will be to actually encode your json as string in the config file:

```
"subOptions_take2": "{\"subOption1\": \"subvalue1_from_json\",\"subOption2\": 200}"
```

then you can just grab it later:

```cs
public IndexModel(IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> options)
{
    _options = options.CurrentValue;
    var subOptions_string = _options.SubOptions_take2;// this is valid json now: {"subOption1": "subvalue1_from_json","subOption2": 200}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @timur.  I may have to stick with encoding the JSON as a string, because the other option is a lot of effort and still doesn't get me where I want to be.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can use `JObject` from Newtonsoft.Json package - it's the default JSON parser & serializer in Asp.Net Core

Comment: There was a typo in my original post. I tried using JObject - it doesn't cause a runtime error, but returns nothing (the configuration data isn't reflected in the MyOptions property)